# Quick way of creating a random subset of an array using IntStream

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

I am wondering if `IntStream` and lambdas can be used somehow to quickly (one-line) create an array containing a random subset of an existing array of elements.

For example, say I have a pool of players:

```
Player[] allPlayers;
```

And I want to get a random subset of those players, given the dimension of the required subset. Traditionally I would do something like:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>(Arrays.asList(allPlayers));

int subsetSize = 8;
Player[] subset = new Player[subsetSize];
for (int i = 0; i < subsetSize; i++) {
  int randIndex = new Random().nextInt(players.size());
  subset[i] = players[randIndex];

  players.remove(randIndex);
}

return subset;
```

But can this process be done with Java 8 features? Which I assume would make it more condensed, which is what I am trying to achieve. I am still getting the hang of these new Java 8 features, like `IntStream` and lambdas and I wouldn't know how to use them for this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you want to select `streamSize` distinct elements from an input array.

You can use the [`Random#ints(randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) method:

> Returns an effectively unlimited stream of pseudorandom int values, each conforming to the given origin (inclusive) and bound (exclusive).

This returns a stream of random integers in the specified range. To ensure distinct values, [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct--) is called and [`limit(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#limit-long-) allows to only keep the number of elements we want.

```
Random random = new Random();
Player[] subset = random.ints(0, allPlayers.length)
                        .distinct()
                        .limit(subsetSize)
                        .mapToObj(i -> allPlayers[i])
                        .toArray(Player[]::new);
```

I would note however, that, even if this is a one-liner, it is not as efficient as [JB Nizet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357209/1743880) since this continues generating integers until a distinct one is found.

Comment: Although this looks nice, I find this strategy suboptimal. If the size is 1000 for example and you want a subset of 999 elements, it will have to generate a whole lot of random integers until finding one that hasn't been generated yet. Collections.shuffle doesn't have this problem. For a small subset, it's probably faster, though.

Comment: Beautiful, this is precisely what I was looking for. I really need to start using lambda's potential. Btw, would you care to explain how `mapToObj` work here?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following, which doesn't use a Stream, isn't a one-liner, but is already more condensed.

```
List<Player> copy = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(allPlayers));
Collections.shuffle(copy);
return copy.subList(0, subsetSize).toArray(new Player[0]);
```

Comment: Right. My question was targeted into figuring out how to do this with `IntStream` and lambdas, but I didn't think of this solution either, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do this is:

```
List<String> players = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
int subsetSize = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < subsetSize; i++)
    Collections.swap(players, i, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(i, players.size()));
System.out.println(players.subList(0, subsetSize));
```

This doesn't require an inefficient search for unused indices if `subsetSize` is large. It doesn't require calling `shuffle` on the entire list, so is more appropriate if `subsetSize` is small. It also avoids calling `ArrayList.remove` which has linear time complexity.

This code does not use `Stream` operations, but I do not think it is possible to write a simple, efficient solution using `Stream` without using a lambda that modifies state (considered bad practice).

Comment: Can you explain your last statement?

Comment: @dabadaba If you were to turn this into a streams solution it would be something like `IntStream.range(0, subsetSize).forEach(i -> Collections.swap(players, i, ...)`. While this works and is far quicker than Tunaki's answer (try that answer with `allPlayers.length == subsetSize == 10_000_000` to see just how slow it is), it modifies the state of `players` inside the lambda, which is not how they're intended to be used.